# how to extend namespace within multiple smart packages

Tags: meteor

I need to create features or modules that consists of multiple meteor smart packages and share the same namespace. The problem is that, if i api.export the namespace in all package.js files then the linker creates a result like that:

```js
/* Imports */
var Meteor = Package.meteor.Meteor;
var MyModule = Package['mymodule-base'].MyModule;

/* Package-scope variables */
var MyModule;
```

So it overwrites the MyModule variable which makes the old scope not usable in other module packages. If i export the variable only in one package then its fine but as soon as i try to include assignment of that variable to code like:

```js
(function (MyModule) {
    MyModule.SomeFeature = ...
})(MyModule || (MyModule = {}));
```

then again the same problem comes up, the linker declares the variable twice, rendering the imported variable useless.

Any reason why this could be intentional or is it a bug? Or how should i solve this situation.

For now i have modified the meteor code to not declare package-scope variable, if it is already declared as imported variables.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to export from a meteor package into my app's namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405802/how-can-i-export-from-a-meteor-package-into-my-apps-namespace)