# How can I export from a Meteor package into my app's namespace?

Tags: javascript, meteor, javascript-namespaces, global-namespace, namespace-organisation

I know [how to write](http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages) [Meteor packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114526/how-to-build-a-meteor-smart-package) but I can't seem to figure out how to have all exports land in my app's namespace, as described [in this presentation](http://meteor.redandivory.com/#/7/1).

This particular package is specific to an app I'm building, and it exports only one method that can be regarded as a decorator on the app's singleton. I tried `api.export('MyApp.myMethod')` but that gives an error `native: Bad exported symbol: MyApp.myMethod`.

If I just `api.export('myMethod')`, then in the app code I have to call `myMethod()`, and that's not namespaced.

Does Meteor have a mechanism similar to Node's `var http = require('http');`? Or how can packages export symbols into a given namespace?

Answer (score 8):

The `api.export` method is only supported for [**top-level variables right now**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meteor-talk/api.export/meteor-talk/YOStFiuzbO8/cZv_W9FjbjYJ). It doesn't work for nested variables, because "*it turned out that using deep exports was 
very confusing*", and what would you expect `MyApp.myMethod` to appear as in the global namespace if you also exported `MyApp.myOtherMethod`?

You should just export `MyPackage`, and then call `MyPackage.myMethod()`. A common approach is to do something like

```
MyPackage = { 
    myMethod: someSecretMethodName,
    myOtherMethod: otherMethodName
}
```

And then call `api.export("MyPackage")`. This means that the exported names of variables don't necessarily have to be what you called them. This is used a lot in the core meteor packages; you can also see an example at for [MongoInternals in mongo_driver.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js).

Comment: So essentially I can't have `MyApp.MyPackage.method()` because that would be a deep export?

Comment: @DanDascalescu you can have that as long as you export the top level `MyApp` variable, with nested `MyPackage` and `myMethod`.

Comment: But that means that the package would need to export `MyApp`, which is semantically dubious. `MyApp` would be the app's global namespace, and @sewdn's [presentation](http://meteor.redandivory.com/#/7/1) suggests that `MyPackage` should become a member of `MyApp`.

Comment: I think you maybe confusing yourself with the nomenclature. The package should export `MyPackage`, which will then become accessible in the namespace of your app, but it will not become a member of the app's namespace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84403/discussion-between-pixelass-and-andrew-mao).

Answer (score 6):

All properties that you register in your app namespace are made available for the packages that depend on (use) your app-package.
So, when you want to register a package namespace in an app-namespace, you declare the dependency on the app-package within your package and you register all of the methods/objects you want to export in the app-namespace. An example:

file: packages/myapp/namespace.js

```
MyApp = {};
```

file: packages/myapp/package.js

```
Package.on_use(function (api, where) {
  api.add_files([
    "namespace.js"
  ], ['client', 'server']);
  api.export("MyApp", ['client', 'server']);
});
```

file: packages/myapp-module1/logic.js

```
packageSpecificMethod = function(){}
moduleOne = {};
//you can export an module-specific namespace by registering it in the app-namespace
MyApp.module1 = moduleOne;
//or you can (if you dont want package-namespaces) register you private methods in the app-namespace directly
MyApp.exportedMethod = packageSpecificMethod;
```

file: packages/myapp-module1/package.js

```
Package.on_use(function (api, where) {
  api.use([
    'myapp'
  ], ['client', 'server']);
  api.add_files([
    "logic.js"
  ], ['client', 'server']);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In your package, you should define all methods and symbols in the namespace you want them to have, and then export that namespace. So, if in your package you've got:

```
MyApp = {
   myMethod: ...
};
```

Then you export it with `api.export('MyApp')`.

Unfortunately, there's no method similar to the one in Node you've mentioned, as all packages are loaded globally on startup.

Comment: Sorry, I've messed up, you need to export `MyApp`, not `myMethod`. Edited the answer now. Also, make sure to add `myPackageCode.js` file using `api.add_files()`.